# How do I create a circled symbol in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, typesetting, mathematical-typesetting

I know that `Framed` is used to show a frame around a symbol, how can I show a circle around a symbol?

Comment: do you mind if the output is a `Graphics` object?

Comment: @yoda If that can be put into a DisplayFormula cell with regular TraditionalForm math symbols, e.g. put braces around it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't mind having to micromanage the alignment parameters, you can overlay the empty circle character over a symbol:

```
TraditionalForm @ Style[
  Overlay[{x, Style[\[EmptyCircle], 24]}, Alignment -> {0.075, 0.16}]
, "DisplayFormula"
]
```

[image: circled "x"]

The exhibited font size and alignment parameters work for the font on my machine, but you may have to tweak them for good results on your screen.  And tweak them again for a decent print-out.  The following `Manipulate` can aid in that process:

```
Manipulate[
  TraditionalForm @ Style[
    Overlay[
      {Style[x, xSize], Style[\[EmptyCircle], circleSize]}
    , Alignment -> {xAlign, yAlign}
    ]
  , "DisplayFormula"
  ]
, {{xSize, 12}, 8, 40, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
, {{circleSize, 24}, 8, 40, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
, {{xAlign, 0.075}, -1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
, {{yAlign, 0.016}, -1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

[image: image adjustment manipulator]

Answer (score 8):

Here is an attempt to create a function that circles arbitrary expressions.  It's rather clumsy, but I cannot think of a better way at the moment.

```
circled =
    With[{m = Max@Rasterize[#,"RasterSize"]},
       Framed[
         Pane[#, {m, m}, Alignment -> Center],
         RoundingRadius -> 1*^6]
    ] &;


circled[1/x + y + z]
```

[image]

Comment: What's the benefit of writing `1*^6` instead of `10^6`?

Comment: @yoda, nothing, just habit.  `1*^6` is my default "large value" and when I see it I often know it is just that: an arbitrary "large" number.  There is one related thing: at the extreme end of things, there is one less operation with `1*^x` than with `10^x`.  For example:  `Timing[a = 1*^60000000;]` and `Timing[b = 10^60000000;]`.

Comment: @yoda Or, perhaps more relevantly:  `Timing@Do[1*^6, {50000000}]` versus `Timing@Do[10^6, {50000000}]`.

Comment: @Mr. I am not the only one being noticed of the convoluted code you are writing lately ....

Comment: @bel Can you do better?  Put up or shut up. ;-))  (I know, this is pretty ugly, but I honestly cannot think of a better way.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I wasn't aware of that performance difference. In this case however, I think it obfuscates more than it educates, but I understand, habits die hard.

Comment: @Mr. If you want to frame whole expressions (and not just simple symbols) the Pane[] size should take the largest diagonal into account. See `circled["3((1/x+y+z)/h)\n2\nm\np"]`

Comment: @bel what should I be seeing in that example?

Comment: @belisarius that's not what I see!  I guess it is system (or setting?) dependent.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/tARbx.gif

Comment: @Mr. Ha! So I posted an answer to solve a semi-existent problem :)

Comment: @belisarius @Mr I get what belisarius gets, but in `TraditionalForm` it's more like what Mr. Wizard gets.

Answer (score 7):

`Framed` can take an option [`RoundingRadius`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Framed.html#127559551).

```
Framed[expr, RoundingRadius -> radius]
```

At smaller values of `radius` the corners of the frame are simply slightly rounded, but at larger values, the frame becomes an oval or circle.

Comment: A combination of nondefault values of `RoundingRadius` and `FrameMargins` seems to do it, but it takes a different combination for each expression I want to put in a circle

Comment: I was hoping you'd be fine with ovals... I'm not aware of a better solution.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to programmaticly calculate the right values of the options.

Comment: Anybody able to whip up a palette button to do this? I've got a palette with a single button to overstrike a selection (from this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112407/23076), and I'd love to add a button to automatically circle it. I'm not so hot with palettes yet…

Answer (score 3):

The same idea of WReach, but trying to autocalculate:

```
cirBeli[x_] := 
 TraditionalForm@
    Style[Overlay[{#, 
       Style[\[EmptyCircle], 
        N@2 Norm[ImageDimensions[Rasterize[#]][[1 ;; 2]]]]}, 
      Alignment -> Center], "DisplayFormula"] &@x

cirBeli[x]
```

[image]

Comment: In `cirBeli[Sin[z^2]/Exp[z] + Integrate[Sin[x] Cos[x] Sqrt[x], x]]`, the expression is not in the middle of the circle.

Comment: @Andrew The problem is that "\[EmptyCircle]" is not vertically centered. Let's see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 2):

### Using Framed[ ] with RoundingRadius

```
f = Rasterize[#, "RasterSize"] &;
circledBeli[x_] := Framed[ x,
                    FrameMargins -> (Norm@f@x - Array[1 &, {2, 2}] f@x)/2,
                    RoundingRadius -> Norm@f@x];

circledBeli[Sin[z^2]/Exp[z] + Integrate[Sin[x] Cos[x] Sqrt[x], x]]
```

[image]

```
circledBeli["3((1/x+y+z)/h)\n2\nm\np"]
```

[image]

**Edit**

The following seems to work better with TraditionalForm:

```
f = ImageDimensions[Rasterize[#]][[1 ;; 2]] &;
g = Reverse[ImageDimensions[Rasterize[Rotate[#, Pi/2]]][[1 ;; 2]]] &;
h = Max /@ Transpose@{f@#, g@#} &;
circledBeli[x_] := 
  Framed[x, FrameMargins -> (Norm@h@x - Array[1 &, {2, 2}] h@x)/2, 
   RoundingRadius -> Norm@h@x];
t = TraditionalForm[Sin[z^2]/Exp[z] + Integrate[Sin[x] Cos[x] Sqrt[x], x]]
circledBeli[t]
```

[image]

Comment: How do you use this with `TraditionalForm`?

Comment: @Andrew As TraditionalForm renders with different horizontal and vertical size under Rasterize[], there is no a straightforward way, AFAIK.

Comment: FWIW, this method behaves strangely when the window is narrower than the object, at least for me.  Example:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/ScOKg.gif

Comment: @Mr. Thanks! Perhaps I'll take a look at it again tomorrow. Time to sleep now.